# How do I get current time on javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a method on visual studio code like this and when I run program, The program allows me to rent a product before the current time and I know `new Date()` method doesn't work on here
how can I solve this?

```
 rent() {
        if (
          this.rentDate > this.returnDate ||
          this.rentDate <new Date()||
          !this.rentDate||
          !this.returnDate
        ) {
              this.toastrService.warning(
                  'Invalid dates'
              );
              return;
          }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `new Date()` "doesn't work" there? Can you clarify?

Comment: Date.now() https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Comment: @IanH. because if it was be working it wouldn't let me to rent a product before the current time ?

Comment: But how do you know that exactly that is the issue? Have you tried debugging to see what the other values contain?

Comment: You need to show how `this.rentDate` and `this.returnDate` are formatted. There are multiple formats a "date" could exist in Javascript. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/492994/6513921

Comment: @MichaelD `rentDate: Date ;
  returnDate: Date ;`

Comment: @MuratAkbyk: Quickest way: Look into [`Date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) and compare it with [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

Comment: @IanH. rentDate and returnDate are formatted as "Date" and when i try to rent after the returnDate it says invalid dates but when i try to rent before the current time it works

Comment: @MichaelD i tried to compare with `Date.getTime()` but it said i can't use < operator with date and number types

Comment: From the attached doc: "_The `getTime()` method returns the number of milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch_". So the comparison `this.rentTime.getTime() < Date.now()` would be a `number < number` comparison. Also note: I **DO NOT** if it take timezone offsets into account.

Comment: @MichaelD       I did what you said it didn't show any errors but it didn't work

Comment: @MuratAkbyk: Try to produce a minimal reproducible example. The data you've provided isn't enough to help.

Comment: **never** use javaScript to get the date if you're planning use in a dbs. You need get the DateTime of the server (the date in a local computer can be any)

Comment: `rentDate: Date` meas rentDate is the JavaScript Date object!

Answer (score 0):

Date.now() creates a timestamp of now

new Date() creates a new date object of when it was created. On this object you can use the date methods (getDay, getMonth etc) as documented here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: i tried how it is here but this time my toastr didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

`rentDate` and `returnDate` were formatted as `Date` and i turned them into `string`then i write this code and it worked:

```
 if (
      Date.parse(this.rentDate) > Date.parse(this.returnDate) ||
      Date.parse(this.rentDate) <  Date.now()-86400000||
      !this.rentDate||
      !this.returnDate
   ) {
      this.toastrService.warning(
        "Invalid dates"
      );
      return;
    }
```